# Getting total price for a ManyToManyField in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to get total price for a ManyToManyField. I'm getting each individual price on price_for_each_item and then I want the total of however many items were in that to be added to 'total_price'

```
class PurchaseOrder(models.Model):
    number_of_products = models.ManyToManyField('Product', null =True)
    total_price = models.FloatField(verbose_name='Total Price')

class Product(models.Model):
    products = models.CharField(max_length=256, null =True)
    price_for_each_item = models.FloatField(verbose_name = "Price")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.products
```

For example, if I made an order of Macbook Pro =$500, Asus Computer =$200, and mousepad= $50. I'd want the total of that to go into total_price = $750

EDIT: I tried doing this, but to no avail. Anyone have any idea what I'd have to do to fix this to work? When I try to display it it says no float object callable

```
    def get_total_price(self):
       return ([p.price_for_each_item for p in self.total_price()])
```

Comment: Are you sure your model structure makes sense? 

If a product is made up of several items you should create an extra model "Item" and have a many-to-many field in Product referring to it? 

Or if a product indeed has just one price, instead of naming the field "price_for_each_item", you should just call it "price". As it stands it's very confusing.

Comment: Sorry I need to reword these models. PurchaseOrder should really have the instance "how_many_products" and then Product should be product and price_for_each_item

Comment: So a product does consist of several items?

Comment: Yes, sir. Here is a screenshot of what it looks like at the moment. (http://i.imgur.com/nibpjug.png?1

Comment: Read carefully. It looks like an order has several products, but does a product consist of several items (i.e. Should it refer to a separate "item" model).

Comment: If I understand correctly, you could just retrieve the sum from the object itself. So if you have an Order called "order" where the products are already assigned (during the saving process, you should be able to something like: order.total_price = order.number_of_products..all().aggregate(Sum('price_for_each_item')). Let me know if this answers your question and I'll move it to an answer.

Comment: Yes! That answers my question. I've never used aggregate though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moved from above.

If I understand correctly, you could just retrieve the sum from the object itself. So if you have an Order called "order" where the products are already assigned (during the saving process, you should be able to something like:

```
order.total_price = order.number_of_products.all().aggregate(Sum('price_for_each_item')).
```

Let me know if this answers your question and I'll move it to an answer.

Glad I could help. Not to be a nazi here, please give more thought to your model field names in the future, they are seriously confusing.

Edit re your comment:

I'm not sure but I think overriding your model's save method would be the way to go to get it to work in admin:

```
def save(self):
        super(Person, self).save()
        self.total_price = self.number_of_products.all().aggregate(Sum('price_for_each_item')). 
        self.save(commit=True)
```

Haven't tested this at all though. Have a look at this:
http://ifacethoughts.net/2009/07/14/calculated-fields-in-django/
If it works, could you accept the answer.

Comment: Awesome. If I were to list this in django admin, would I make it a definition and then call it in list_display? for example, would this be something like  def  get_total price(self):    order.total_price = order.number_of_products.all().aggregate(Sum('price_for_each_item'))

Comment: I tried putting the def save function in my PurchaseOrderAdmin class and/or PurchaseOrder class and both times I got the error "PurchaseOrderAdmin.list_display[1], 'get_total_price' is not a callable or an attribute of 'PurchaseOrderAdmin' or found in the model 'PurchaseOrder'.
"

Comment: Sorry, can't tell you off the top of my head. You'll have to do a bit of research there. Have a look at the link I included in the answer.

Comment: It's all good. Where would you put the definition though? Would it be in models under PurchaseOrder? Under admin.py under PurchaseOrderAdmin.

Comment: As I wrote in the answer, the save method is in the model class.

Answer (score 1):

No need to add the `dollar_amount` field, that is duplicate information. Instead make it a property, this is how you get the total price:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

p = PurchaseOrder.objects.filter(...)
p.annotate(Sum("products__price_for_each_item")
```

Comment: Hmmm, I'm still not super familiar with properties. How would I display this in the list_display of admin? or I guess would there be a way to make this a definition so I could easily put it in my list_display?

Comment: I was thinking of the same thing, but actually if the price changes later on, you don't want the sum on the order to change.